# Why no scroll bars on Table?

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to get scroll bars on the table, but they are just not showing up no matter how I try. Here is what I have so far:

'''

```
# Table Frame
tree_frame = Frame(root, bg="#ecf0f1")
tree_frame.place(x=0, y=380, width=1980, height=520)
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", font=('Calibri', 18),
                rowheight=50)  # Modify the font of the body
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 18))  # Modify the font of the headings
tv = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), style="mystyle.Treeview")


#scrollbar
tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_frame)
tree_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_frame,orient='horizontal')
tree_scroll.pack(side= BOTTOM,fill=X)

my_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame,yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, xscrollcommand =tree_scroll.set)


tv.column("# 1",anchor=W, stretch=NO, width=100)
tv.heading("# 1", text="ID")
tv.column("# 2", anchor=W, stretch=NO)
tv.heading("# 2", text="Catagory")
tv.column("# 3", anchor=W, stretch=NO, width=150)
tv.heading("# 3", text="Brand")
tv.column("# 4", anchor=W, stretch=NO, width=255)
tv.heading("# 4", text="Model")
tv.column("# 5", anchor=W, stretch=NO, width=375)
tv.heading("# 5", text="Serial#")
tv.column("# 6", anchor=W, stretch=NO)
tv.heading("# 6", text="Notes")

tv['show'] = 'headings'
tv.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", getData)
tv.pack(fill=X)
```

'''
Anyone have any ideas? Here is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollbars are there. The problem is that you're using `place` on `tree_frame` which prevents the window from resizing to fit the widgets. If you manually make the window large enough, the scrollbar will become visible.

If you use `pack` or `grid` with appropriate options, the window will automatically resize to make all of the widgets visible.

```
tree_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```